# Is there something I can use to uniquely identify a device connecting to a socket with Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm working on an app that keeps users together in a room using socket.io. While using the app, I'm keeping track of actions the users take. If a user disconnects accidentally (in my use case, their phone rings, or the screen shuts off), I want them to be able to re-enter the room as the same 'user' without requiring a login so the actions they've tracked stay with them. I tried using `socket.conn.remoteAddress`, but that doesn't seem to be consistent enough to rely on.

For now, I'm requiring the user to manually enter a username and match to the user with that name on the server, but I'd rather it be automatic and invisible to the user, not to mention more reliable than what each user inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cookie.  When they connect, check if their unique cookie already exists.  If not, create it with a unique ID in it.  If it does already exist, use the unique ID in it to identify the user.

From the connect event in socket.io, you can get the cookies here.

```
const socketCookieName = "socketUser";
const cookieParser = require('socket.io-cookie-parser');
io.use(cookieParser());

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // all parsed cookies in socket.request.cookies
    
    let user = socket.request.cookies[socketCookieName];
    if (!user) {
         // create unique userID and set it in a cookie
         user = /* create some unique userID here */;
         // set this into a cookie
    }
    // now user will be your socket.io userID

});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I need and I feel dumb for not having though of it.